# Testflight installing issue

Tags: ios, ipad, testflight

My client trying to install app using **`TestFlight`** it is showing **Couldn't Load App** **(`TestFlight` couldn't connect to itunes to itunes connect. Try again later.)**[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read lots of blogs and post regarding this issue. And tried many things like :

- remove build and upload build again.
- remove `TestFlight` testers and add them again.
- un-install `TestFlight` and re-install again.
- Restarting the `iPad`. And Resetting all settings on the `iPad` (factory defaults).

But issue was still there. Then finally I have asked to my client, What is `iOS` version in his `iPad`? Actually he was use **11.2.6**. Then I have told him to update `iOS` in `iPad` to **11.3** because I have set **11.3** in project's `Deployment Target`.

And finally issue have been resolved.

I hope this will help to others.